# If any user with some free time can help me with my array loop

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

```
function changeImage(image)
{
var patharray = image.src.split('/');
var name = patharray[patharray.length -1];
if (name == "FlyingHigh.png") {
}
else
```

my loop is missing some code I know but i need it done, please include html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come on... at least post some *seemingly* valid code... with an actual question.

```
function changeImage(image)
{
    var patharray = image.src.split('/');
    var name = patharray[patharray.length -1];
    if (name == "FlyingHigh.png") {
        ...
    }
}
```